# Black-screen after enabling SLI or MultiGPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed.
My Graphics Card is Nvidia GeForce GT755M SLI

Whenever i enable SLI or MultiGPU the screen goes black after bootlogo.
The bootlogo appears, when the bootload is finished screen goes black and i cant do anything. I have to shutdown the computer with the power button.

I tried to enable SLI in two different ways.

1. By editing the xorg file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

> Section "Screen"

```
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "on"
Option         "MultiGPU" "off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
```

EndSection

I also tried turning the MultiGPU but still got blackscreen 
Then i turned both on and still got blackscreen.

2. I tried to enable it by running the following commands in terminal

> sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=On

I still experienced blackscreen

I also enabled MultiGPU by using the following command

> sudo nvidia-xconfig --MultiGPU=on

still did not help

Please answer if you have any solutions.

Specs:

Computer:               Lenovo Y510P

Graphics card:          Nvidia GeForce GT 755M SLI

Processor:              4th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ (2.4GHz 1600MHz 6MB)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Disable "Allow Flipping" under OpenGL Settings in the NVIDIA X Server Settings.

You will see what those settings are, from a terminal window, with  `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`